# What is the AC of a Wall of Bone?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, armor-class

The spell [Wall of Bone](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wall%20of%20Bone) details a number of statistics about the sections of wall created, including HP, but the description says nothing about AC. It is based on [Wall of Stone](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wall%20of%20Stone) but that spell does not mention AC either.

Did I miss some more generic rule about the AC of this sort of spell? Do attacks against the wall just always hit since it has no AC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Walls are Objects; Objects' AC varies slightly but is very low

TL;DR: Walls are no less than Large and are unable to defend themselves, so I would rate their AC around 2.

Inanimate object (such as structures, including walls and [Walls](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-stone/)) Armor Class is detailed in [Damaging Objects](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/). Specifically,

> Objects are easier to hit than creatures because they don’t usually move, but many are tough enough to shrug off some damage from each blow. **An object’s Armor Class is equal to 10 + its size modifier (see Table: Size and Armor Class of Objects) + its Dexterity modifier.** An inanimate object has not only a Dexterity of 0 (–5 penalty to AC), but also an additional –2 penalty to its AC. Furthermore, if you take a full-round action to line up a shot, you get an automatic hit with a melee weapon and a +5 bonus on attack rolls with a ranged weapon.

\begin{array}{r|lll}
\text{Size} & \text{AC Modifier} \\
\hline
Colossal & -8  \\
Gargantuan & -4 \\
Huge & -2 \\
Large & -1 \\
Medium & 0 \\
Small & +1 \\
Tiny & +2 \\
Diminutive & +4 \\
Fine & +8 
\end{array}

Based on this, Medium objects have an AC of 3. Anything larger has less (down to -5...?) and smaller objects may have more, up to 11 to hit a grain of sand or similar.

Comment: Depending on how you define "defend" a wall of fire or flesh wall can defend itself.

Comment: Fair, but it doesn't seem like it will get out of the way lol

Answer (score 2):

**Probably AC3, but your DM may rule otherwize.**

The descriptions of both spells don’t give the exact AC, but suggest that these walls have the same features as a nonmagical stone wall except for those mentioned in the spell description.

A stone wall at the same time is an object. The [rules for objects](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Breaking%20and%20Entering&Category=Exploration) give the general formula for object AC’s:

> An object’s Armor Class is equal to 10 + its size modifier (see Table 7–11) + its Dexterity modifier. An inanimate object has not only a Dexterity of 0 (–5 penalty to AC), but also an additional –2 penalty to its AC. Furthermore, if you take a full-round action to line up a shot, you get an automatic hit with a melee weapon and a +5 bonus on attack rolls with a ranged weapon.

Thus a section of a stone wall would have an AC of 3 or lower depending on which size you assigne to it.

Though the rules don’t say explicitly whether a section of a stone wall is Medium, Large or Huge (or whatever), the section on [Urban Adventures](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Walls%20and%20Gates&Category=Urban%20Features) describes a number of stone sity wall types:

> Many cities are surrounded by walls. A typical small city wall is a fortified stone wall 5 feet thick and 20 feet high. Such a wall is fairly smooth, requiring a DC 30 Climb check to scale. The walls are crenellated on one side to provide a low wall for the guards atop it, and there is just barely room for guards to walk along the top of the wall. A typical small city wall has **AC 3**, hardness 8, and 450 hp per 10-foot section.
>
> A typical large city wall is 10 feet thick and 30 feet high, with crenellations on both sides for the guards on top of the wall. It is likewise smooth, requiring a DC 30 Climb check to scale. Such a wall has **AC 3**, hardness 8, and 720 hp per 10-foot section.
>
> A typical metropolis wall is 15 feet thick and 40 feet tall. It has crenellations on both sides and often has a tunnel and small rooms running through its interior. Metropolis walls have **AC 3**, hardness 8, and 1,170 hp per 10-foot section.

As you see each of these walls has an AC of 3. I think it is safe to assign AC 3 to a wall produced by the spell. At least unless it has some unusual shape.

Answer (score 0):

It is a non-animate object. This means it shares the AC of all non-animate unmoving objects.

This is covered under the [damaging object rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/#TOC-Breaking-and-Entering).

> Objects are easier to hit than creatures because they don’t usually move, but many are tough enough to shrug off some damage from each blow. An object’s Armor Class is equal to 10 + its size modifier (see Table: Size and Armor Class of Objects) + its Dexterity modifier. An inanimate object has not only a Dexterity of 0 (–5 penalty to AC), but also an additional –2 penalty to its AC. Furthermore, if you take a full-round action to line up a shot, you get an automatic hit with a melee weapon and a +5 bonus on attack rolls with a ranged weapon.

Splash weapons a bit different and covered under [ranged/splash attacks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon).

> You can instead target a specific grid intersection. Treat this as a ranged attack against AC 5. However, if you target a grid intersection

So what is the AC of the wall spells for melee? It depends on how you build them. Lets say that the smallest wall you build is medium (since its AC modifier is 0). That means the highest AC for the wall spells is base 10 + size 0 - dex 5 - 2 = 3 AC. Larger objects become easier to hit.